# How to convert legend to graphics in QGIS?

Tags: convert, print-composer, qgis-2, legend, image

In QGIS am trying to convert the legend element in the print composer into graphics, like the option in the ArcGIS "Convert To Graphics", see image below

[image]

Is there some way to do it with QGIS?

Comment: Well, unfortunately... there's no way my friend.

Answer (score 4):

I use a way "around the corner" with **Inkscape**, an open source tool for editing vector graphics:

1. Add a second page to the print composer of your map.
2. Add a legend and move the "raw" legend on the second page.
3. Export the print composer as svg (every page of the print composer will be exported as own .svg-file)
4. Open the svg of the second page with Inkscape and edit your legend (nearly) as you are used in ArcGIS
5. Re-import the legend as an image.

This way you have the chance to design your legend with much more possibilities. The disadvantages are that the quality of the re-imported image is not the same like an original legend and that you always have to do a detour over an external program.

So here my question: 
Is there still no way to convert legends to graphics in QGIS directly?